# (How) can I publish a Google Sheet and associated Google Apps Script organization-wide and avoid or suppress authorization prompts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Our organization uses Google Apps for Work. We have a Google Sheet "form" for employees/users to complete. After entering information, users are expected to use email as attachment/PDF. Finally, users click a "button" near the bottom of the sheet that triggers a script to clear user data. The first time a user clicks the button, an "Authorization Required" prompt appears, informing the user "the application" (script) "needs authorization to run." If approved, the prompt goes on to request *View and manage your spreadsheets in Google Drive* permissions for the script.

Is it possible to digitally sign or otherwise pre-approve a Google Apps Script for all users in a Google Apps organization so this prompt doesn't appear? We can/will include instructions for users, to head off questions / allay fear, but many of our users will either ignore or not understand the instructions and be perplexed.

I'm open to (and exploring) other options for tackling this (Google Forms/Sheets?), but prefer to stay in the (native) Google Apps environment as much as possible.

I couldn't find this question elsewhere and as best as I can tell, it isn't answered in Google Apps Script documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I have found no way to pre-approve an organization/group/individual without manually doing it for each account.

You CAN deploy the script using a service account and have it run as that account.  Then you are authorizing that account and the end user's accounts do not come into play.  The drawback is that if you want the emails to go out using the end user's email, it won't happen.  Plus the sending of the email would have to be from code in the app.  That means all emails would go out using the service account's email address.  (Although I am now wondering if it is possible to initiate the email without sending it.  Basically pop it up as if a mailto link was clicked.)

You also will not be able to get the end user's name, etc.  If these items are not important, or you can trust them to fill out their name where it may be needed (you could change the From name to what they key in) then running as the service account may work for you.

Karl